# Rotating LineRenderer's length to Stop at GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am attempting to get a LineRender to rotate with a GameObject. I want it to start at the center of its parent GameObject and extend till it encounters another GameObject. Much like how a laser pointer would work if you were standing in a room and rotating around.

[image]

The below code semi-works in that it shoots a `LineRenderer` to the center of any `GameObject` as it rotates. So it jumps. This is the example C red line in the picture above.

Additionally,  my "walls" are in a Unity tilemap with the tag of "block", so the only objects that are returning valid to the `RayCast2D` are the ones outside of the tile map. The walls do have `TileMap Collider 2D` attached.

Lines A and B are representative of what I would like to happen. But, those not show up as the walls are in a tile map.

***Any help?***

```
private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
private int xRot = 0;    
private void Awake() {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        if (lineRenderer != null) {

            lineRenderer.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, -3); // Put this higher up so the camera can see
            lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.2f;
            lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.2f;
            lineRenderer.useWorldSpace = true;
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        }
    }


    private void void Update() {

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, xRot);
        xRot++;
        xRot = (int)Mathf.Repeat(xRot, 360);

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.up * 10, Color.red);

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformPoint(Vector2.up));
        var distance = GetDistance(transform.position, hit.collider.transform.position);

        Vector3 endPos = transform.position + (hit.collider.transform.position.normalized * distance);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, endPos);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the laser jumping around, instead of using the collider's position, you can use the `point` at which the raycast hits the collider.

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformPoint(Vector2.up));

if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.tag == "block")
{
    Vector3 endPos = hit.point;
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, endPos);
}
```

I haven't worked with tilemaps, but according to the [unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-Physics2D.html), the TileMap colliders should work the same as a normal collider.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The answer was right there the entire time. Thank you!